# Do calculations on regex capture group in gulp

Tags: javascript, regex, npm, gulp, gulp-replace

I need to write a script to restructure some code to new syntax, while also multiplying\dividing some of the present values.

TLDR:

For example i want to turn:

```
oldFunction(3, "text");
oldSize = 3;
```

into

```
newfunction("text", 3);
newSize = 6; //notice that this is oldSize*2
```

I managed the replace and reorder part with gulp-replace and regex, but I don't know how to multiply numbers in regex capture groups.

FULL:

More detailed example:

```
font size = 34px;
text position = {5, 42};
```

I use regex and gulp-replace to restructure it into new syntax:

```
.pipe($.replace(/font size = (.+)px;\ntext position = {(.+), (.+)}/g, 'createText($2, $3, $1);'))
```

And I get:

```
createText(5, 42, 34);
```

All good - old numbers are now in all the right order!

Now, the problem: Can I somehow do basic math manipulations (multiplication, division) to the old numbers before replacing?

Also. If there is more practical tool for such task - I'll be happy to use it.

Comment: Try replacing `'createText($2, $3, $1);'` with `function($0,$1,$2,$3) { return $2 + $3 + $1*2; }`

Comment: @Wiktor 
Yep. This works, thanks!
Maybe you should post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regular [anonymous callback method inside `.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to be able to manipulate group values.

```
.pipe($.replace(/font size = (.+)px;\ntext position = {(.+), (.+)}/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) { 
    return 'createText(' + $2 + ', ' + $3 + ', ' + $1*2 + ');'; 
 }))
```

The last value will be multiplied by 2.

You should consider using a digit matching pattern (`[0-9]+`) instead of a wildcard-like `.+` (where `.` matches any char but a line break char) for that kind of code to work safely.